# Link to actual record from map info window

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table with a map view. I'd like to add a link on the bottom of the map info window to be able to edit that specific record. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create the edit UI yourself using the Fusion Tables API. There's no built-in link that can pull the record itself for editing, although it's a nifty idea.

-Rebecca